# How to get Strings from getDefaultSharedPreferences in non Activity like normal Class? Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

currently in work with my Own Weather API, it run on my own PC.
So i work with View Model and androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen.
I text is save with EditTextPreference.
But if i try to get that saved Strings out of SharedPref. and it Crash.

Here is the Companion Object Function that cause. CRash
fun

```
setServerAddress() : String {
            val app = this as Application
            val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(app)
            val ipInput = prefs.getString(app.getString(R.string.pref_Key_IP_Input), "")?.trim()
            return ipInput.toString()
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well your code won't work because `this as application` will fail unless its actually an Application (which a companion object never is).  The way to do this is to pass in a Context as a parameter:

```
setServerAddress(context: Context) : String {
            val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            val ipInput = prefs.getString(app.getString(R.string.pref_Key_IP_Input), "")?.trim()
            return ipInput.toString()
}
```

Comment: thx, for answer and how i initialize it?